# Error "cannot convert 'std::basic_string<char>' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int system(const char*)'"

Tags: c++, string, char, system

I get this error: "invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [6]' to binary 'operator+'" when I try to compile my script. Here should be the error:

```
string name = "john";
system(" quickscan.exe resolution 300 selectscanner jpg showui showprogress filename '" + name + ".jpg'");
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The type of expression

```
" quickscan.exe resolution 300 selectscanner jpg showui showprogress filename '"+name+".jpg'"
```

is `std::string`. However function system has declaration

```
int system(const char *s);
```

that is it accepts an argumnet of type `const char *`

There is no conversion operator that would convert implicitly an object of type `std::string` to object of type `const char *`.

Nevertheless class `std::string` has two functions that do this conversion explicitly. They are `c_str()` and `data()` (the last can be used only with compiler that supports C++11)

So you can write

```
string name = "john";

system( (" quickscan.exe resolution 300 selectscanner jpg showui showprogress filename '"+name+".jpg'").c_str() );
```

There is no need to use an intermediate variable for the expression.

Answer (score 18):

`std::string + const char*` results in another `std::string`.  `system` does not take a `std::string`, and you cannot concatenate `char*`'s with the `+` operator.  If you want to use the code this way you will need:

```
std::string name = "john";
std::string tmp = 
    "quickscan.exe resolution 300 selectscanner jpg showui showprogress filename '" + 
    name + ".jpg'";
system(tmp.c_str());
```

---

See [std::string operator+(const char*)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator+=)

Answer (score 4):

The addition of a string literal with an `std::string` yields another `std::string`. `system` expects a `const char*`. You can use `std::string::c_str()` for that:

```
string name = "john";
string tmp = " quickscan.exe resolution 300 selectscanner jpg showui showprogress filename '"+name+".jpg'"
system(tmp.c_str());
```

Answer (score 4):

As all the other answers show, the problem is that adding a `std::string` and a `const char*` using `+` results in a `std::string`, while `system()` expects a `const char*`. And the solution is to use `c_str()`. However, you can also do it without a temporary:

```
string name = "john";
system((" quickscan.exe resolution 300 selectscanner jpg showui showprogress filename '"+name+".jpg'").c_str());
```

Answer (score 3):

The system function requires const char *, and your expression is of the type `std::string`. You should write

```
string name = "john";
string system_str = " quickscan.exe resolution 300 selectscanner jpg showui showprogress filename '"+name+".jpg'";
system(system_str.c_str ());
```