# c++ error: cannot convert basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'long int strtol

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I'm new to C++, been programming a while in C though.
Trying to read in a string and then convert the string into int by using strtol.
Iam using the gcc compiler.
And I get the following error message: "c++ error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'long int strtol(const char*, char**, int)'       int c = strtol(str[j], &p, 10);".
I have tried different types of conversions but really like the strtol for future reference. Is there something to do with my vector string?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
using std::string;

int main()
{
  int a = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int size = 0;
  int* big;

  cin>>a;
  size = a*2;

  int sizes[size];
  string *str = new string[size];
  while(i < a){
    cin>>str[i];
  i++;
}

i = 0;
while(i < a){
  cout << str[i] << endl; // just for checking
  i++;
}



for (int j =0; j<size-1;j++){
  char* p;
  char* q;
  int c = strtol(str[j], &p, 10);
  if (!*p) {
     sizes[j] = *p;
  }else{
     sizes[j] = *p/2;
  }
}

return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you reduce the code to whats causing the error? Or at least mention which line it is?

Comment: `int sizes[size];` is not standard C++, this is an extension which means this code is not portable. Also `using std::string;` is rendundant when you also have `using namespace std;`. Also you never delete `string *str = new string[size];` (which you should, although an ever better solution would be `std::vector`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot convert 'std::basic\_string<char>' to 'const char\*' for argument '1' to 'int system(const char\*)'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589353/cannot-convert-stdbasic-stringchar-to-const-char-for-argument-1-to-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strtol(str[j].c_str(), &p, 10)`; the call to `c_str()` returns a `const char*` that points at the contents of the string object, and `strtol` wants a `const char*`. Or you can write more idiomatic code, and call `std::stol(str[j])`.