# Running certutil -hashfile with standard inputs for filepath and hashtype (c++)

Tags: c++, string, cin, certutil

First time posting.
I am trying to write a simple program that takes a file path and a hash type from standard input, and outputs the corresponding hash using certutil. Later I would like to compare the hash to one that the user enters, and output a pass or fail statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

string hash_type;
string path_to_file;

cout<<"Enter full file path to hash: "<<endl;
cin>>path_to_file;
cout<<"\nFilepath is: "<<path_to_file;
cout<<"\nWhich hash to use? (e.g SHA256)"<<endl;
cin>>hash_type;
cout<<"\nHash type is: "<<hash_type<<endl;
```

*I have tried with or without the cout;*

```
cout<<system("certutil -hashfile path_to_file hash_type");
```

> system("certutil -hashfile C:\Users\moose\Desktop\current.cpp SHA256")

This will run perfectly fine, and I see the resultant hash. I just can't seem to use the strings from standard input. I suspect it could have something to do with the extra backslash needed in the filepath or another delimiter?

```
return 0;
}
```

I'm still learning about pointers, but I have also tried the following; system("certutil -hashfile *path_to_file *hash_type");
since I am getting the following error:

> Certutil: -hashfile command FAILED: 0x80070002
> Certutil: The system cannot find the file specified.
> 'hash_type' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system.

Answer (score 0):

I have got it working.

```
string hash_args = "certutil -hashfile " + path_to_file + " " + hash_type;
system(hash_args.c_str());
```

This was very helpful:
[cannot convert 'std::basic_string<char>' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int system(const char*)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589353/cannot-convert-stdbasic-stringchar-to-const-char-for-argument-1-to-i)